# useNavigate sometimes works, sometimes doesn't (after API call)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I made a login page in TS React that sends an API request to authenticate the user.

The API call returns a token, after that the user should be redirected to `"/"` (if successful).

Returning the token works 100% every time, but the redirect sometimes fails.

It seems like the page is being rerendered instead of redirecting. What am I doing wrong?

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Login() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState<string>("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>("");
  const [tokenProvided, setTokenProvided] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "Login";
    if(tokenProvided){
      navigate('/')
    }
  }, [tokenProvided]);


  const handleLogin = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const loginData: loginData = { username, password };
      const responseData = await getLoginToken(loginData);
      localStorage.setItem("token", responseData.token);
      const userAuthentificationToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
      axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${userAuthentificationToken}`;
      setTokenProvided(true);
    } catch (error) {
      createErrorToast("Invalid username or password.");
    }
  return (
    <Page backgroundColorActive={false} navbarActive={false}>
      <LoginFormWrapper>
        ...bla...

        <LoginForm onSubmit={handleLogin}>
          ...bla...
          <LoginFormButton type="submit">Login</LoginFormButton>
        </LoginForm>
      </LoginFormWrapper>
    </Page>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

The behaviors is as follows:

- I enter the credentials on the page
- I hit submit
- I can see it working (takes a moment for the api call to return)
- The site rerenders
- I can see the token in local storage

Sometimes it will in fact redirect, but I don't know why or how or when.

Edit:
Here is my route protection:

App.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ProtectedRoute, { ProtectedRouteProps } from "./helper/restrictedRoute";

const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("token") !== null;
const defaultProtectedRouteProps: Omit<ProtectedRouteProps, "outlet"> = {
  isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated,
  authenticationPath: "/login",
};

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        {/* Unprotected routes: These routes can be accessed without being logged in */}
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        {/* Protected routes: These routes can only be accessed while being logged in */}
         <Route index element={<ProtectedRoute {...defaultProtectedRouteProps} outlet={<Home />} />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```

RestrictedRoute.tsx:

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

export type ProtectedRouteProps = {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  authenticationPath: string;
  outlet: JSX.Element;
};

export default function ProtectedRoute({ isAuthenticated, authenticationPath, outlet }: ProtectedRouteProps) {
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return outlet;
  } else {
    return <Navigate to={{ pathname: authenticationPath }} />;
  }
}
```

The routing protection seems to be the problem, the else statement in RestrictedRoute.tsx gets executed, but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to cll `navigate` from the `handleLogin` instead of enqueueing a state update and waiting for a component rerender? That said, I don't see any overt issue in the code you've shared that would cause the issue you describe. Can you [edit] to provide more debugging details? Are there any errors?

Comment: i tried that at first, but it showed the same behaviour. i can only provide details on how it behaves:
- i enter the credentials on the page
- i hit submit
- i can see it working (takes a moment for the api call to return)
- the site rerenders
- i can see the token in local storage

Comment: Have you implemented route protection? Is it possible you ***are*** getting navigated and the route protection is redirecting user back to login? If so can you [edit] to include the router/routing code as part of a more complete [mcve]? If possible can you also try creating a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: hey Drew, i implemented protection, i will provide the code in main post shortly

Comment: i just checked, the "else" statement in RestrictedRoute gets executed, but i still dont know how to fix

Comment: i did it, thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The localStorage is checked only once when the `App` file/component is processed/mounted. `isAuthenticated` is computed once ***outside*** anything in the app.

```
const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("token") !== null;
```

The localStorage check should be moved ***into*** the `ProtectedRoute` and checked when the component renders. `ProtectedRoute` should also render the `Outlet` component for *protected* nested routes to render their content into.

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

export type ProtectedRouteProps = {
  authenticationPath: string;
};

export default function ProtectedRoute({ authenticationPath }: ProtectedRouteProps) {
  const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("token") !== null;

  return isAuthenticated
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to={authenticationPath} replace />;
}
```

The routes written as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ProtectedRoute, { ProtectedRouteProps } from "./helper/restrictedRoute";

const defaultProtectedRouteProp: ProtectedRouteProps = {
  authenticationPath: "/login",
};

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        {/* Unprotected routes: These routes can be accessed without being logged in */}
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />

        {/* Protected routes: These routes can only be accessed while being logged in */}
         <Route element={<ProtectedRoute {...defaultProtectedRouteProps} />}>
           <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```